# iOS Swift App Memory Issue - Remove Function from Memory After Running?

Tags: php, ios, json, xcode, swift

First time questioner...I've got an iPad Kiosk mode app that is installed at a couple of Schools.  They have intermittent internet issues and instead of the App not responding I built a bit of code that checks to see if the server is actually reachable.  I tried the Reachability.swift and Apple's Reachability files, which I've also implemented, but they fail to go far enough and actually see if the internet connection is working...

My problem is each time the code reaches out to the server, it adds a bit of overhead to the memory, and eventually, the memory fills up.  I'd like to remove the overhead after the function runs, but I can't seem to find how to do it.  Any help would be appreciated!

The function connects to my Server, and if the app can't connect after 5 seconds it times and and throws an error and Displays an Alert, if it connects, it does nothing (except eat up some memory).  The connection file on the server is PHP and just contains a header

```
<?PHP header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); ?>
```

Here's my code:

I call the function from viewDidLoad:

```
override  func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

weak var testConnectionTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("testConnection"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

//WebView UI Here}

//The testing Function

func testConnection(){


        var  connected = 0
        let urlAsString = "https://www.myserver.com/app/online.php"
        let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5.0
        let urlSession = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)


        let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {

            }

            if (error == nil) {
           connected = (connected + 1)

            }
            if (connected != 1)
            {

            var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "MySystem", message: "Can't Connect to Server.  Please Verify Internet Connection and Try Again", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Try Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
                    UIAlertAction in
                    self.ActivityMonitor.startAnimating()
                    NSLog("Try Again")
                self.WebView.reload()
                    let isDisplayed = 0
                }
                var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Exit App", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
                    UIAlertAction in
                    NSLog("App Exited")
                    exit(1)
                }


                alertController.addAction(okAction)
                alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }

        })

        jsonQuery.resume()
       }
```

Comment: Whenever you're having memory issues and are not sure how to proceed, I recommend using Instruments. I'm not sure how well Instruments works with Swift, though, so proceed with caution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this view controller ever dismissed? If so, your repeating timer will prevent the it from being deallocated. The `NSTimer` maintains a strong reference to its target, and the timer itself won't be released until you call `invalidate`.

I would suggest watching WWDC 2013 video [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) and WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242) which show you techniques for using Instruments to identify leaks, abandoned memory and retain cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions!  After reviewing "instruments" it was indeed the NSURLSession.  I added

```
urlSession.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

at the end of the Function and that seems to have plugged the "hole"